# How to control a cursor position in c++ console application?

Tags: c++, console-application, text-cursor

I'm supposed to create a console application for school project and it's about Sudoku Game, so the thing is i don't find any struggle with the algorithm, but i was wondering if i could draw the full Sodoku table with c++ and make empty squares as "data" input place so the user can move the cursor using the arrow keys to the specific number's place to fill it with the appropriate number.

Is there a method to do it this way ?

Comment: Sounds like you want a GUI; I suggest you look for a library you like the look of (Qt is a good start or perhaps Open GL)

Comment: How best to do that depends on what operating system you are using, e.g. windows or linux. For linux there's the ncurses library, for windows there's the Console API.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your OS/Compiler. For example, in VC++ you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) and example can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-high-level-input-and-output-functions).

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(){
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD pos = {3, 6};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, pos);
WriteConsole(hConsole, "Hello", 5, NULL, NULL);
return 0;
}
```

If you want to do it in Linux with g++ compiler, you can use special libraries such as curses or write your own implementation(will be a bit difficult). Such for just placing the cursor at the required position, you can use this:

```
void gotoxy(int x,int y)    
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}
void clrscr(void)
{
    system("clear");
}
int main() {    
    int x=10, y=20;
    clrscr();
    gotoxy(x,y);
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Using say system("**cls**"); or even "rem" works in VS too. Original clrscr shows: **'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**, but gotoxy also works then ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In windows you should use windows api.

from there, use `SetCursorPos()` for it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) library for creating text-based user interfaces. It works fine with Linux and with Windows under Cygwin/MinGW.